# On scroll autoscroll to next div

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I saw some homepages with a cool script making the scroll action as a autoscroll to the next div. 
Here's what I mean in a better way: You start of in the hero part, and then when you use scroll to scroll down on the page, the script forces the homepage to lock itself to the next div in lets say hero 2 with a smooth animation, is there some kind of plugin for this or can anyone be kind enough to post a script that does that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [ScrollMagic.js](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/) or [Skrollr.js](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr). ScrollMagic's great because you can use [Greensock](http://greensock.com/gsap) to animate your elements. [Check out this scrollMagic tutorial](https://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-scrollmagic-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

As [Agent Zebra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30768890/778975) mentioned there are lots of JavaScript library out there to do this sort of thing.

In the future there will be another way of doing it without JavaScript, using [CSS scroll snap points](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-scroll-snap-points). Firefox added [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=snap) in version 39, but support in other browsers is lacking right now.